# Outlook API Get Messages not returning Attachment collection

Tags: node.js, outlook, outlook-restapi

I am using the Outlook Mail REST API to get JSON objects of a collection of a user's emails and display the data in a custom web interface. I need to show a list of emails, and each email in the list needs an indicator of the NUMBER of attachments for that particular email.

I am using the Get Messages from `Outlook Mail REST API reference #Getmessages` route to get all of the data I need to do this. However when I specify in my `$select` that I want `Attachments`, I never get the Attachment collection for each email; it's just missing.

I can get the attachment collections for each individual email with an individual request for each email, which will be ugly if I need Attachment counts for 100 emails at once.

According to this: (https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/api/complex-types-for-mail-contacts-calendar#RESTAPIResourcesMessage)
I should be able to specify if I want the attachment collection when I Get Messages, but it isn't working. I am using Node.js to get the email collection:

```
var requestUrl = "https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/messages";

var queryParams = {
    '$select': 'Subject, ReceivedDateTime, From, ToRecipients, HasAttachments, Attachments, WebLink, CcRecipients, Body',
    '$orderby': 'ReceivedDateTime desc',
    '$filter' : dateString,
    '$top': 300
};

...
```

[Returned Email Object in Collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1qqq9.png)

Every option in `$select` is working correctly if I include it or exclude it, but `Attachments` is always missing. Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Attachments` is a navigation property, so you need to request that it gets "expanded" by appending a `$expand` parameter:

```
https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/mailfolders/inbox/messages?
  $select=Subject,Attachments&$filter=HasAttachments eq true&$expand=Attachments
```

Comment: Thanks so much, here is a link to you answer in the docs. [https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/api/complex-types-for-mail-contacts-calendar#UseODataqueryparameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/api/complex-types-for-mail-contacts-calendar#UseODataqueryparameters)